# Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module

Tags: java, scala, maven, spring-boot

I am getting this error while running `spring boot application`.

When I am giving build it is successful but when calling the API getting an error like below.

Please help me.

I am calling a `RestController` Method through API which was creating a `spark session` in that method.

`Spark UI` is getting started but in console seeing below error and also return message is not showing in the Browser.

`Whitelabel Error Page`

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

**Tue Nov 07 14:36:51 IST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module**

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:229) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$$anonfun$registerSinks$1.apply(MetricsSystem.scala:198) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$$anonfun$registerSinks$1.apply(MetricsSystem.scala:194) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99) ~[na:na]
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99) ~[na:na]
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230) ~[na:na]
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40) ~[na:na]
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.registerSinks(MetricsSystem.scala:194) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.start(MetricsSystem.scala:102) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:522) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2313) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:868) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:860) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860) ~[spark-sql_2.11-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at com.tam.ui.DemoController.home(DemoController.scala:19) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]



My Maven pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TestSpringBoot</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestSpringBoot</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>

    </parent>

     <properties>

        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!--<start-class>me.wonwoo.Application</start-class>-->
        <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
     </properties>


     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                 <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>

                  </exclusion>
                  <exclusion>
                 <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
                  <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
                  <exclusion>
                  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
                   <exclusion>
                  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>

                  </exclusion>

            </exclusions>     
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope> 
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                 <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>

                  </exclusion>
                  <exclusion>
                 <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
                  <exclusion>
                  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>

                  </exclusion>
                  <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
                  <exclusion>
                  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
            </exclusions>     
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
                 <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
             <version>2.9.1</version>
              <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
                  </dependency>
                  <dependency>
                 <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
             <version>2.9.1</version>
                  </dependency>
                  <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
               <version>2.9.1</version>
                  </dependency>
                  <dependency>
                 <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                 <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
             <version>2.9.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-parameter-names -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.2</version>
            </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>           
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive_2.11 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>

   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>

</dependency>

        </dependencies>
     <build>
     <plugins>
     <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>


     </plugins>

     </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have is multiple versions of jackson in your uber jar, 
so what you need is **shading rules** to rename the the jackson libs that spark uses to some other name. you will have both versions in the classpath but under different names. I myself use sbt so I've never done it with maven but you can start here [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) it also explains what shading is. 


~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
**But in a nutshell, what shading does is:**
Rename all usages of some lib **com.fasterxml.jackson.** ** 
to some rule you define, for example **shaded_xml.@1**.
and what you get in result is:

1. another directory in the class path with the name: **shaded_xml**, and in it, all your classes as in the original **com.fasterxml.jackson**
2. all the classes using **com.fasterxml.jackson.** ** rewritten to use **shaded_xml.** ** instead.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
To check your shading rules, you can actually open your jar and look for the new directory in the class path. 
You can also look in some class file you know has usage of the original lib name 
and check if it was renamed

Answer (score 0):

Remove Jackson related libs from exclusions and it should work.

Comment: spark uses jackson as it's json serilizer, parser, etc... so removing it completely will not solve the problem but will make things worse, this means he has different versions of jackson so he needs to add shading rules which will give different named to different versions and all needed versions could be found in the classpath, but again - under different names.